# Grafana dashboard - select columns in table

Tags: grafana

Creating a dashboard with a listing of the persistent volumes in my Openshift cluster.

The table, however, lists ALL of the labels as columns, like over a dozen columns.

I only want node, namespace, persistentvalueclaim, values displayed.

I can't figure out how to display only these columns in my table.

My query:

```
(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes
  * on (namespace, persistentvolumeclaim) group_left (storageclass, provisioner) 
  (kube_persistentvolumeclaim_info
     * on (storageclass) group_left (provisioner) 
     kube_storageclass_info{provisioner=~"(.*rbd.csi.ceph.com)|(.*cephfs.csi.ceph.com)"}))
```

I expect to see some kind of 'fields' section of the table edit display, but I don't see that.

Answer (score 0):

To hide some of the columns in Table panel you can use Transformation [*Organize fields*](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#organize-fields).

> [With this transformation] you can:
>
> - Change field order by hovering your cursor over a field. The cursor turns into a hand and then you can drag the field to its new place.
> - Hide or show a field by clicking the eye icon next to the field name.
> - Rename fields by typing a new name in the Rename box.

In your case you simply need to add this transformation and click an eye icon next to every column you don't want to see in the table, leaving mentioned three ones.